# owl carousel theme icons not clickable for url page

Tags: url

I have a theme for my website that is using owl carousel and i can add icons with descriptions, but i cannot add individually a link for each icon. is going for all together.
If anyone can give me a help to understand how i can add the url to each icon would be great :)[menu where i can change icon and name, no option for url](https://i.stack.imgur.com/K5c0C.jpg) [owl carousel](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BQH6O.jpg). i can provide php file for that section if anyone can help.

Thank you

I managed to get te same url for all the icons